# Python: Modifying a class' list for specific objects

Tags: python, class, object

So I have a list of objects in which I have a list. The list has common strings and is supposed to have some specific strings for every object depending on another variable.

```
class test: 
   strings = []
   name = None
```

Then I'm creating a list of objects

```
objects = []
i = 0
while i < 2 :
   o = test()
   o.name = "Object " + str(i)
   objects.append(o)
   i += 1
```

Then I'm adding general strings for both objects in the list

```
test.strings.append("String 1")
test.strings.append("String 1")
```

What I need is for each object to have a specific string after those, so I tried

```
test.append("testing")
for element in objects :
   print element.strings[ len(element.strings) - 1 ]
   element.strings[ len(element.strings) - 1 ] = element.name
   print element.strings[ len(element.strings) - 1 ]
```

The output I'm getting is

```
testing
Object 0
Object 0
Object 1
```

And when I try to access element.strings where that string is it always is the last modification.

I tried appending individually, also, instead of doing the test.append before the for, but it added elements to every object. Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do?

**Edit against duplicate:**
What the other question is asking is how to have independent data with no shared information. What I want is shared information with a few instances of specific data.

Comment: Please show real code. That would fail with `NoneType object has no attribute 'append'`, because `strings` is None not a list.

Comment: Why don't you use `pdb` to debug and check values at every step?

Comment: I'm sorry, I modified it accordingly. strings = []

Comment: I guess this is what you want:

http://pastebin.com/0u1bBH2j

(I don't agree that this question is a duplicate, I have to use the comment field as the question is closed at the moment)

Comment: Yes. Thanks a lot. I will look into this, I did a workaround using dictionaries with the key being the position in which the specific string would be in the general strings array.